# TDD rule and Java contract conflict

Tags: java, tdd, equals, hashcode

Rule one of TDD is this:

`Write production code only to pass a failing unit test`

Effective Java Item 11(third edition), that is the same contract of java Object.hashCode():

`Always override hashCode when you override equals`

Now which is correct to do if we need to override only equals to pass a failed test and we need not to use object in a collection in the current failed test and it may be happened in future?

Comment: First of all: those are "only" guidelines. Second, if we write a test to verify that `equals(...)` is working as expected, we should also write a test that assures that `hashCode()` satisfies the contract between `equals(...)` and `hashCode()`. So no contradiction here.

Comment: but we don't need to override `hashCode()` for the current test at all (now).

Comment: Again: then we write a test that verifies that the contract between `equals(...)` and `hashCode()` holds. By the line of argumentation given, we will be able to write a failing test that can be fixed by overriding `hashCode()` in the unit under test. This enables us to override `hashCode()` under the constraints given.

Comment: Yes, I understand this, but my problem is this that we concentrate on a problem that we don't need to it at all now and may be never. My question is not this that how to fix this contradiction, but the effort that we do on a problem that is not recommend in TDD.

Comment: If you don't want to override hashcode, you don't think you need it, then you don't have to. Just be aware your leaving bear-traps in your code.

Comment: Why not use Lombok or something like it? Saves a ton of boilerplate coding and testing.

Comment: Great. It's a good way but the question is remained in my mind yet @don-branson

Answer (score 1):

> Always override hashCode when you override equals

Try this spelling: if you have to override `equals`, then your work *is not done* until you've also overridden `hashCode`.

So don't merge/share/publish the work until all of the required elements of the contract are complete.

But you can do the work in whatever order you like.